# How to sketch the graph of an implicit in two dimentional space xy?

Tags: graphing-functions

I am looking for a software able to sketch the graph of $y = y(x),$ where: 
${e^y} + y{e^y} + {e^{ - y}} = 4 - 2\cos x$

your help is highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What about Wolfram Alpha? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ey%2Bye%5Ey%2Be%5E%28-y%29%3D4-2cosx

Answer (score 1):

What about [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ey%2Bye%5Ey%2Be%5E%28-y%29%3D4-2cosx) or [Desmos](http://desmos.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to plot (for a suitable range of $y$)
$$
x(y) = \pm\cos^{-1}\left(2 - \tfrac{1}{2}({e^y} + y{e^y} + {e^{ - y}})\right) +2\pi n 
$$
for $n = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2,...$

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica can do this. The code is {ContourPlot[E^(-y) + E^y (1 + y) + 2 Cos[x] == 4, {x, x_0, x_1}, {y, y_0, y_1}]}

Comment: I wrote the code that you gave in mathematica but I received an error

Comment: I wrote the code that you gave in mathematica but I received the following error:

Comment: I wrote the code that you gave in mathematica but I received the following error: \!\(ContourPlot::"plnr" \(\(:\)\(\ \)\) "\!\(\(\(\[ExponentialE]\^\(-y\) + \(\
\(\[ExponentialE]\^y\\ \(\((1 + y)\)\)\)\) + \(\(2\\ \(\(Cos[x]\)\)\)\)\)\) \
== 4\) is not a machine-size real number at \!\({x, y}\) = \
\!\({\(\(-1.7142857142857144`\)\), \(\(-2.`\)\)}\)."\)

Comment: The x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1 are the bounds of the graph, you have to insert numbers there.

Answer (score 0):

The graphic of $y=y(x)$ is the same as that of $x=x(y)$, rotated by $90^\circ$. The whole idea is to find the intervals for which the left hand side lies between $4-2=2$ and $4+2=6$, since $|\cos x|\le1$. Otherwise, $\arccos$ might inevitably return an error. Which is why I would recommend GeoGebra, which doesn't seem to have these sort of issues.